# pivot_longer into several pairs of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

I'm needing to `pivot_longer` across multiple groups of columns, creating multiple names--values pairs.

For instance, I need to go from something like this:

```
df_raw <- tribble(
  ~id, ~belief_dog, ~belief_bull_frog, ~belief_fish, ~age, ~norm_bull_frog, ~norm_fish, ~norm_dog, ~gender,
  "b2x8",    1,           4,          3,         41,     4,       2,          10,         2,
  "m89w",    3,           6,          2,         19,     1,       2,           3,         1,
  "32x8",    1,           5,          2,         38,     9,       1,           8,         3
)
```

And turn it into something lie this:

```
df_final <- tribble(
  ~id,   ~belief_animal, ~belief_rating, ~norm_animal, ~norm_rating, ~age,   ~gender,
  "b2x8",    "dog",           1,          "bull_frog",      4,        41,       2,
  "b2x8",    "bull_frog",     4,          "fish",           2,        41,       2,
  "b2x8",    "fish",          3,          "dog",            10,       41,       2,
  "m89w",    "dog",           3,          "bull_frog",      1,        19,       1,
  "m89w",    "bull_frog",     6,          "fish",           2,        19,       1,
  "m89w",    "fish",          2,          "dog",            3,        19,       1,
  "32x8",    "dog",           1,          "bull_frog",      9,        38,       3,
  "32x8",    "bull_frog",     5,          "fish",           1,        38,       3,
  "32x8",    "fish",          2,          "dog",            8,        38,       3
)
```

In other words, anything starting with "belief_" should get pivoted in one names--values pair & anything starting with "norm_" should be pivoted into another names--values pair.

I tried looking at several other Stack Overflow pages with somewhat related content but wasn't able to translate those solutions to this situation.

Any help would be appreciated, with a *strong* preference for `dplyr` solutions.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can pivot on the two sets of columns that starts with `belief` and `norm`. We can then use regex to split into groups according to the first underscore (since some column names have multiple underscores). Essentially, we are saying to put `belief` or `norm` (the first group in the column name) into their own columns (i.e., `.value`), then the second part of the group (i.e., animal names) are put into one column named `animal`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_raw %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(starts_with("belief"), starts_with("norm")),
               names_to = c('.value', 'animal'),
               names_pattern = '(.*?)_(.*)') %>% 
  rename(belief_rating = belief, norm_rating = norm)
```

**Output**

```
  id      age gender animal    belief_rating norm_rating
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>       <dbl>
1 b2x8     41      2 dog                   1          10
2 b2x8     41      2 bull_frog             4           4
3 b2x8     41      2 fish                  3           2
4 m89w     19      1 dog                   3           3
5 m89w     19      1 bull_frog             6           1
6 m89w     19      1 fish                  2           2
7 32x8     38      3 dog                   1           8
8 32x8     38      3 bull_frog             5           9
9 32x8     38      3 fish                  2           1
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it with a bit more experimentation!

The key comes down to both the `names_to` & the `names_pattern` arguments.

```
df_raw %>% pivot_longer(
  cols = c(belief_dog:belief_fish, norm_bull_frog:norm_dog),
  names_to = c(".value", "rating"),
  names_pattern = "([a-z]+)_*(.+)"
)
```

I don't really understand how `".value"` or the regex `"([a-z]+)_*(.+)"` work, but the solution works nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

For these data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_raw %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(id, age, gender),
    names_to = "name1",
    values_to = "belief_rating"
  ) %>% 
  separate(name1, c("A", "B"), sep = '\\_' , extra = 'merge') %>%  
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(helper = rep(row_number(), each=3, length.out = n())) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = A,
    values_from = B,
    names_glue = "{A}_animal"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(norm_rating = ifelse(helper == 1, lead(belief_rating, 3), NA),
         norm_animal = ifelse(helper == 1, lead(norm_animal, 3), NA)) %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  select(id, belief_animal, belief_rating, norm_animal, norm_rating, age, gender)
```

```
  id    belief_animal belief_rating norm_animal norm_rating   age gender
  <chr> <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 32x8  dog                       1 bull_frog             9    38      3
2 32x8  bull_frog                 5 fish                  1    38      3
3 32x8  fish                      2 dog                   8    38      3
4 b2x8  dog                       1 bull_frog             4    41      2
5 b2x8  bull_frog                 4 fish                  2    41      2
6 b2x8  fish                      3 dog                  10    41      2
7 m89w  dog                       3 bull_frog             1    19      1
8 m89w  bull_frog                 6 fish                  2    19      1
9 m89w  fish                      2 dog                   3    19      1
```